# Center The Main Navigation Bar

Tags: css, navigation, themes

Trying to center the main navigation bar in the the HitMag wordpress theme.

Here is an example of the site, https://www.goldenira.net

The main nav bar at the top is aligned to the left. I want it to align to the center.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```css
.navigation{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <h1>Hello!<h1>
<div>
```

> display: flex;

This applies flex to the container

> justify-content: center;

This is going to center the div in it.

**Great** tutorial and cheatsheet about flex is [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me to figure it out. I was able to center it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. And for a return, could you click that [green tick](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `.main-navigation` css class use `display: flex;`

Comment: This was also helpful. Both answers helped me to edit the CSS and center it.